# What’s the meaning of might in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Mr. Brocklehurst, I believe I intimated in the letter which I wrote
>   to you three weeks ago, that this little girl has not quite the
>   character and disposition I could wish: should you admit her into
>   Lowood school, I should be glad if the superintendent and teachers
>   were requested to keep a strict eye on her, and, above all, to guard
>   against her worst fault, a tendency to deceit.  I mention this in your
>   hearing, Jane, that you may not attempt to impose on Mr.
>   Brocklehurst.” 
>  **Well might I dread, well might I dislike Mrs. Reed**; for
>   it was her nature to wound me cruelly; never was I happy in her
>   presence; however carefully I obeyed, however strenuously I strove to
>   please her, my efforts were still repulsed and repaid by such
>   sentences as the above. (Jane Eyre)

What’s the meaning of *might* in the sentence, and what are these two clauses meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will usually encounter the idiom in this case as “You may well X”. It has two meanings:

- One is, “It is very likely that you will X”. *If you read much fiction you may well find unusual and difficult English constructions.* In this case *may* is used in the sense *be possible that*.
- The other is approximately, “You are quite right to X” or “If you X, that will be a good thing”—or a smart, or a prudent, or an appropriate thing, depending on the context. This is often uttered as an agreement with or amplification of someone else’s observation: *You may well say that!* In this case, *may* is used in the sense *be permitted or entitled to*.

In your example, Jane is employing the second meaning, cast in the past tense (*may* ⇨ *might*), and inverted for rhetorical effect—you will have noticed that Jane tends to get a little melodramatic at times. “I was quite right to dread and dislike Mrs. Reed.”

Comment: Thank you, now I can see ‘well might’ feeling of Jane in the moment.

Comment: I agree you've drawn the correct distinction. I think *If you drive while drunk, you might well have an accident and kill someone*, is a more "modern" form that uses *well* along the lines of Estuary English *"Don't mess with him - he's well 'ard!"* (i.e. - as an intensifier). Brontë's usage is "approbatory" - it's *right & proper, correct, understandable, fitting* that Jane feels antipathetic towards Mrs Reed, rather than highly likely, or implying even more antipathy than we might otherwise have supposed.

Answer (score 5):

One of the functions of *might* is to express possibility, so the sentence means that there was a very strong possibility that Jane should dread and dislike Mrs Reed. In the context it tells us that she had good reason to do so. *Well* is here 'used as an intensive to strengthen the idea implied in the verb, or to denote that the action, etc., indicated by it attains a high point or degree' (OED).

Comment: Then, can I understand the sentence as “It might well I dread, it might well I dislike Mrs. Reed.”?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. The construction has to be as Charlotte Brontë wrote it.